# Entity Framework 4 and SQL Compact 4: How to generate database?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, sql-server-ce

I am developing an app with Entity Framework 4 and SQL Compact 4, using a Model First approach. I have created my EDM, and now I want to generate a SQL Compact 4.0 database to act as a data store for the model. I bring up the *Generate Database Wizard* and click the *New Connection* button to create a connection for the generated file. The *Choose Data Source* dialog appears, but SQL Compact 4.0 is not listed in the list of available data sources:

[image]

I am running VS 2010 SP1 (beta) and I have installed the VS 2010 Tools for SQL Compact 4.0. I can create a SQL Compact 4.0 data connection from the Server Explorer. It is only in the *Generate Database Wizard* that the 4.0 option doesn't appear. BTW, my SQL Compact 4.0 installation does include `System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll`. So I should have the SQL Compact components I need.

Am I doing something incorrectly, or is this a bug? Does anyone have a fix or a workaround? Thanks for your help.

Comment: David, have you looked at using SQLite instead of CE? I've found SQLite to be easier to work with and fully supports EF4.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As a workaround, I am using the *Generate Database Wizard* to generate a a SQL Compact 3.5 script, which I am running against a blank SQL Compact 4.0 database created in the VS 2010 Solution Explorer. Here are the steps to accomplish that task:

**Step 1:** Run the *Generate Database Wizard*. It prompts for the creation of a file on its first page, so have it create a SQL Compact 3.5 file. This file is a dummy, so it doesn't matter what you name it.

**Step 2:** Complete the wizard to create the DDL script that will configure the new database.

**Step 3:** Delete the dummy file created in Step 1.

**Step 4:** Use VS 2010's Server Explorer to create the actual SQL Compact 4.0 file that you will use in your project.

**Step 5:** The *Generate Database Wizard* places two references to SQL Compact "3.5" in the EDMX file; these references need to be changed to "4.0". Open the EDMX file in VS 2010's XML Editor (right-click and select 'Open With' to get to the XML Editor). Line 7 should contain the "3.5" references. Change these to "4.0" and save the file.

**Step 6:** Open the generated EDMX.SQLCE script file in VS 2010. VS will indicate (via a banner across the botton of the work pane) that the script is disconnected. Right-click on the white space above the banner and select *Connection > Connect* in the context menu that appears. That brings up a connection dialog--use it to connect the script to the SQL Compact 4.0 database that you created in Step 4.

**Step 7:** Right-click in the script white-space again and select *Execute SQL* from the context menu. The script will execute and you will get the usual results message in a pane below the script. Assuming successful execution, the database is then configured to match the Entity Data Model.

**Step 8:** We also need to ensure the App.config/web.config is not pointing to the dummy file. If it is change it to the actual CE 4.0 file created in Step 4 above. Else we have trouble with regeneration of the script when we make change to the model. In the config file change 3.5 to 4.0 as well.

At that point, you should be able to use Entity Framework 4 to work with your database.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the comments below and address them according to:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/01/12/microsoft-sql-server-compact-4-0-is-available-for-download.aspx

These wizards to not work.

Designers in the VB or C# Windows projects in Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Beta: The following wizards do not work with Compact 4.0 in the Windows project system. Developers can manually add reference to the ADO.NET provider for Compact 4.0 (System.Data.SqlServerCe) to develop programs for Compact 4.0 in the Windows projects:

1. The Data Source Configuration Wizard that is used to configure datasets.
2. The Configure Data Configuration wizard that is used to setup the syncing of data and schema with SQL Server using Sync FX.
3. The Entity Data Model wizard that is used to generate entities from a Compact database.

Here are the accepted work arounds for these issues.
http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/11/using-entity-framework-with-sql-server.html

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is with Entity Framework 4. EF4 has a *Generate Database Wizard* that will generate a T-SQL script for a SQL Compact database from an Entity Data Model. It's the *Generate Database Wizard* that isn't showing SQL Compact 4 as a generation option.

Comment: If your going for a Transact SQL db script CE syntax is no different than SQLServer. You should be abel to just generate the tables and such with that script.  I see what your saying. Have you tried to add a connection with the server explorer? And see if it will come up after you establish the connection? Wish i could be of more help.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it current version of VS 2010 doesn't have support for SQL CE 4.0. It should be included in VS 2010 **SP1** (currently in Beta). Check [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/11/vs-2010-sp1-and-sql-ce.aspx) which also describes using EF Model with SQL CE 4.0 in SP1.

**Edit:**

I found this [workaround](http://getsrirams.blogspot.com/2010/10/adonet-entity-data-model-for-sqlserver.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I've got SP1 and the VS Tools installed. The blog post doesn't really address my problem--it's geared toward db-first and code first, and I'm doing model-first.

Comment: I found some workaround when searching for another thing. I added link to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use IDatabaseInitializer and create the database in code using

```
if (File.Exists("Test.sdf"))
    File.Delete("Test.sdf");

string connStr = "Data Source = Test.sdf; Password = <password>";

SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine(connStr);
engine.CreateDatabase();
engine.Dispose();

SqlCeConnection conn = null;

try {
    conn = new SqlCeConnection(connStr);
    conn.Open();

    SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE myTable (col1 int, col2 ntext)";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

catch {
finally {
    conn.Close();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceengine(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yet another, use WebMatrix database tool.

[Microsoft WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/)

Answer (score 0):

I can run Generate Database Wizard with out any issue from my Chinook.Data project, make sure you have a proper connection string in your app.config. http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/11/using-entity-framework-with-sql-server.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ChinookEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ChinookModel.csdl|res://*/ChinookModel.ssdl|res://*/ChinookModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=C:\projects\Chinook\Chinook40.sdf&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks, Erik--when you run the Generate Database Wizard, do you have an entry for SQL Compact 4.0? The Wizard runs for me, but it doesn't show Ver. 4.0 as an option.

Comment: I just get the second screen with the DDL generated, but it does not show 4.0 connections in step 1, that is true. You will have to move the edmx to a Web Project in order to see 4.0 connections in step 1

Comment: I developed a workaround that enables creating a SQL Compact 4.0 database from an Entity Framework 4 EDM, without having to use a Web project. See the accepted answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably need the [SQL Server Compact 4 tools](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/5/D/05DCCDB5-57E0-4314-A016-874F228A8FAD/SSCEVSTools-ENU.msi) installed as well, if it did not install directly when Visual Studio 2010 SP1 was installed, you can install it.  This is what worked for me when I had the problem.