# Where is SQL Server CE 4.0 data provider for Visual Studio?

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce

Where is SQL Server CE 4.0 data provider for Visual studio?

I want to use SQL Server CE 4.0 with Entity Framework. I have installed all packages but it's missed in list of available providers for EF?

Is it supposed to be so, or I miss something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework 4 and SQL Compact 4: How to generate database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205280/entity-framework-4-and-sql-compact-4-how-to-generate-database)

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 adds this capability ...

Answer (score 0):

Probably need the [SQL Server Compact 4 tools](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/5/D/05DCCDB5-57E0-4314-A016-874F228A8FAD/SSCEVSTools-ENU.msi) installed as well, if it did not install directly when Visual Studio 2010 SP1 was installed, you can install it.  I had to do this myself.