# Entity Framework 4 with SQL CE 4 Problem

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I created a entity framework 4.0 application by creating a model. The SQL Server Compact edition 4.0 database is created with [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205280/entity-framework-4-and-sql-compact-4-how-to-generate-database).

Now I finished all my code for importing the initial data into my database (Adding elements works fine). But if I try to access the elements via

```
 Context context = new Context();

 foreach (var c in context.Customers) // Exception
 {
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(c.ToString());
 }
```

it throws an exception at the start of the foreach loop:

```
[A]System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection cannot be cast to 
[B]System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection. Type A originates from 
'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' in the context 'Default' at location
'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.SqlServerCe\4.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\
System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll'. Type B originates from 'System.Data.SqlServerCe, 
Version=3.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' in the context
'Default' at location  'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.SqlServerCe\
3.5.1.0__89845dcd8080cc91\System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll'.
```

I added these references to my application:

```
System.Data.Entity - 4.0
System.Data.SqlServerCe - 4.0
System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity - 4.0
```

Does anyone has an idea, what is wrong with my configuration?

*PS: I want to use SQL CE 4.0 because of the computed values. If I need to use 3.5, I need to change my architecture (Or is it possible to implement something like computed values inside the context class?).*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think your edmx file (look at it in a XML editor) still references 3.5, change that to 4.0

Comment: You are right. I changed the version before, but modified something after that. The version was reverted back to 3.5. Thanks!