# How do I get Entity Data Model to work with SQL Server CE 4.0?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I am trying to use Entity Framework with SQL Server CE 4.0. I installed VS10 SP1 with SQL Server CE etc. but when I tried to create an Entity Datamodel (.edmx), only SQL Server Compact 3.5 is shown as a provider, 4.0 is not on the list.

What should I do to get this to work?  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205280/entity-framework-4-and-sql-compact-4-how-to-generate-database), perhaps you find something helpful

Comment: I can answer when it comes to ASP.NET MVC 3 (particularly when using Code First), but I don't think that will necessarily help your situation here. Let me know if you're curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design, you can only do that in Web projects. But with SQL Server Cpmpact Toolbox, you can do it in any project type: http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com